# Html Using select to redirect to frame

Tags: html

Heres another problem...

What I want to do is target a frame to display with a dropdownbox

```
  <p align="center"><b>Select a Site </b>
    <select onchange="window.open(this.value,'','');">
    <option value="">Select one</option>
        <option value="http://www.altavista.com" target="iframe_a">1</option>
        <option value="http://www.yahoo.com" target="iframe_a">2</option>
         <option value="http://www.google.com" target="iframe_a">3</option></select>
         <input type="button" value="Go"
    onclick="window.open(setit.options[setit.selectedIndex].value)">
    </p></form>
```

But when I try this it apperently doesnt work.

Hope somone can find a solution because its kinda enoying me right now.

EDIT:

I know that it is 'window open'
Can somone please correct it, thats why im asking the question.
please give code :D
or example
Cheers, -*Geekz*

Comment: window.open opens a new browser window. It has nothing to do with iframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a jsfiddle that does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/r5RBr/.  The key is changing the `src` of the iframe.  Below is the code from the fiddle.

```
<iframe height="300px" width="500px" id="iframe_a"></iframe>

<form>
    <p align="center"><b>Select a Site </b>

        <select onchange="document.getElementById('iframe_a').src=this.value">
            <option value="">Select one</option>
            <option value="http://www.altavista.com" target="iframe_a">1</option>
            <option value="http://www.yahoo.com" target="iframe_a">2</option>
            <option value="http://www.google.com" target="iframe_a">3</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" value="Go" />
    </p>
</form>
```